# Android Integration with NewRelic

Tags: android, newrelic

I try to integrate the newrelic plugin to my project but alway crash by

I include

```
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:4.+"
  }
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'new relic'
```

and

```
  compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.AsyncTaskInstrumentation
        at com.kogi.hitchradiolib.HitchBaseApplication$1.handleMessage(HitchBaseApplication.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post the build.gradle file in its entirety?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:4.+'
    }
}
apply pluggin: 'newrelic'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'
}
```

Comment: No i doing that but a generate the class no found error